# mod_rewrite ignore last directory if it's the third directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would you remove the last directory if the url contains three directories

```
For example this url
www.mysite.com/dir/removeMe
would map to 
www.mysite.com/dir

However 
www.mysite.com/dir
would still map to 
www.mysite.com/dir
```

I am trying to use prettier links instead of www.mysite.com/dir/?name=removeMe

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]+)$ /$1
```

You can also use `$2` in the rewrite if you want to preserve the last directory name in a parameter or something. eg:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]+)$ /$1?foo=$2
```

(Aside: I notice that by 3 directories you actually mean 2. That first thing is the hostname, not a directory.)

Comment: that doesnt seem to be working. I am first removing the .php at the end of the file so maybe you can show it with www.mysite.com/dir.php/removeMe and then I can try to remove the .php after I am able to remove the last directory

Comment: Perhaps you want something like this? `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /$1.php` That removes the second level directory, and appends `.php`

Comment: I created what I hope is a better question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453730/ignore-last-directory-if-it-is-the-second-directory-mod-rewrite

Comment: @Mike: it's really the same question with slightly different wording. You should just edit this question, not create a new one.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?marker=$1 [L] this is what I ended up going with. Thanks.