# ignore last directory if it is the second directory mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to setup a mod_rewrite that will do the following

```
www.mysite.com/dir/ignoreMe
will map to
www.mysite.com/dir
however in the browser the url will still appear to be
www.mysite.com/dir/ignoreMe

if the url entered is simply
www.mysite.com/dir
the rewrite shouldn't do anything.
```

This way I can use the last/ second directory as if it was a GET query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]+)$ /$1
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?marker=$1 This is what I ended up going with. A variation of your example.